# Return string results arent correct

Tags: java, string, replace, reverse

This is my code, i want users to enter a word or a phrase, then the user can remove all characters, remove a single character, replace a character with another one and reverse characters.

Each individual function works by itself, but when i put it in the while loop the string i print out is the same as the user's input.

Basically the functions that is within the string didn't work. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

The loop kinda messed me up, if someone can test the code and that would be really awesome!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter;
        String str, str1;
        boolean play=true;

        System.out.println("Enter the string to be manipulated:");
        str=scan.nextLine();
        while(play==true){

            System.out.println("Enter your command (quit, print reverse, replace all, replace single, remove");
            str1= scan.nextLine();

            if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("print reverse"))
            {

                String reverse = "";
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
                String s=scan.nextLine().trim();

                int length = s.length();

                for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
                    reverse = reverse + s.charAt(i);
            }

            else if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("replace all"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
                String s=scan.nextLine().trim();
                s=str.substring(0,1);

                System.out.println("Enter the new character");
                String r=scan.nextLine().trim();
                r=str.substring(0,1);

                str=str.replace(s, r);

            }
            else if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("replace single"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
                String s=scan.nextLine().trim();
                s=str.substring(0,1);

                System.out.println("Enter the new character");
                String r=scan.nextLine().trim();
                r=str.substring(0,1);

                System.out.print("Which "+ s+ " do you want to replace?");
                int index=scan.nextInt();

                for (int i =0; i<str.length();i++){
                    if(str.substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                        index--;
                    if(index==0)
                        str=str.substring(0,i)+r+str.substring(i+1,str.length());
                }

            }
            else if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("remove"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
                String s=scan.nextLine().trim();
                s=str.substring(0,1);

                str.replace(s,"");
            }

            else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                System.exit(0);
            else
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid command");

            System.out.println(str);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using a system.exito(0); set your boolean play variable to be false when the user enters "quit" and that will finish your program.

Comment: Neither "remove" nor "print reverse" set a new value for `str`. "print reverse" asks for a whole new string. "replace single" I'm not even sure because you scan a line then start pulling stuff out of the string to manipulate. It's pretty hard to wade through all this code, though.

Comment: and unless you have to use a loop for the menu, it would be easier for you and the JVM to use a switch case instead of that while.

Comment: in your `print reverse` you do not asigne `reverse` to `str` for example and why ask there fo a string to reverse if you already have the string `str`?

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr.  The OP hints the whole point is to put it in a loop, which is really not related to how the decision of what manipulation to do is made at all.

Comment: Do all of your functions fail, or just one? I can see several problems with the `print reverse` command - you're declaring a Scanner which you never use, and you also never use `str`.

Comment: as people already stated, you are not asigning the new value of the string to your str variable in some methods.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's printing the input when you do `println(str)` and never change the value of `str`.

Example: In the case of `"print reverse"`, you build a new reversed string in the variable called `reverse`, but you then don't do anything with it. Maybe a `str = reverse` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you ask for the string to be manipulated and store it in `str`, but in the reverse task, you ask for a new string and store it in `s`.

Then you build a reversed string in the variable `reverse` but you don't keep it anywhere - it goes out of scope.

In the remove task, you don't store the result of the `replace` method. This method does not change `str`, it returns a new string containing the changes.

Then you check `str` for the command to quit, but you should be checking `str1`.

**Tips**

Choose good variable names. The extra time spent typing them is much less than the time you save when it is easy to see what they are for.

Indent your code - I already edited your question. See how much easier it is to read?

Always use { and } for if, for, while, do, etc. It makes it easy to understand and reduces potential bugs when another line of code is added that is supposed to be in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look good you will notice somrthing odd: 
1. When you reversed a String, you saved the reversed String at a local variable and did nothing with it (String reverse) 
2. in replace single, you scanned for a char (a string, actually) but you soon overrided the value with the first character of str. 
You did the same with the String r (copy & paste? ;) ). 
Than you replaced a char wiyh the same char => we stayed with the original String, str. 
This is in both replace single and replace all. 
3. The same as (2) happened in remove.

I would have recommend to part this into function, one replacing single, one replacing all, one removing and one reversing. 
In addition, when cipy and pasting the same code cayses the same errors/unexpected outputs. Be careful when doing it!